# lua embeded in html with apache

Tags: apache, lua, mod-lua

Apache has `mod_lua`. Is there a way to have it process an html page with a  like tag similar to php?

If not is there some other method? (I've seen `mod_plua` but it doesn't seem to have much work towards it).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it actually, but [Haserl](http://haserl.sourceforge.net/) is something what you might need.

It was reported to be working in the lua-users [mailing list](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-10/msg00466.html).

> Haserl is a small cgi wrapper that allows "PHP" style cgi programming, but uses a UNIX bash-like shell or Lua as the programming language. It is very small, so it can be used in embedded environments, or where something like PHP is too big.

## P.S.

I haven't worked with it, so I'm not eaxctly sure if it works.

Answer (score 1):

For php-style Lua programming, you could definitely use mod_pLua.
Contrary to what your initial statement says, it does have a lot of work put into it, just look at the extra features supported by it.
Whether or not mod_lua will support this kind of programming in the future...who knows :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your config. In your Apache config, add the following lines of code:

```
AddHandler lua-script .lua
AddHandler lua-script .htm .html
```

That should set the handler for html files to mod_lua (not tested as I don't use this mod).

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. I already had lua files working fine. That or it's not `<?lua`.